# c++: Iterating through a multiset of vectors

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, multiset

I am attempting to print out all of the elements in each vector from a multiset of vectors. The build is failing but the error is occurring somewhere in a header file, I'm afraid I don't really understand the error codes at all. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Here is the error:

```
error: invalid conversion from 'const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >* const' to 'std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*'
```

And here is the code causing the problems.

```
multiset<vector < string > > setOfRules;
vector<string> testing,testing2;

testing.push_back("bar");
testing.push_back("foo");
testing2.push_back("foo2");
testing2.push_back("bar2");
setOfRules.insert(testing);
setOfRules.insert(testing2);

for (multiset< vector <string > >::iterator myIterator = setOfRules.begin();
     myIterator!=setOfRules.end(); 
     ++myIterator) 
{

    for (vector< string >::iterator myOtherIterator = ( *myIterator ).begin(); 
         myOtherIterator != ( *myIterator ).end(); 
         ++myOtherIterator) 
    {
        cout << *myOtherIterator << " " ;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: I failed to see where you added `testing` and `testing2` to `setOfRules`.

Comment: Agreed.  `setOfRules` is empty in this code.

Comment: iterating a `multiset` requires you use a `const_iterator`. Otherwise, you could attempt to change the 'key' of the set during iteration, which would break the ordering in the set.

Comment: So I guess @GrimFandango found the issue, along with the missing addition of the vectors. Go ahead and answer it.

Comment: Fixed that empty multiset problem. Cheers for pointing that out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C++11 Standard claims that for associative containers where the **value type is the same as the key type**, both **iterator** and const_iterator are **constant iterators**.

So actually `multiset<vector<string>>::iterator` is `const_iterator`. The same trick with `std::set` iterators - they are all consts.

This means that `vector<string>::iterator myOtherIterator = *myIterator.begin()` statement will fail because you try obtain **non-const** iterator from **const** object (given by `*myIterator` which is `const`).

To fix you need to use `vector<string>::const_iterator`:

```
for(multiset<vector<string>>::const_iterator myIterator = setOfRules.begin(); 
    myIterator != setOfRules.end(); ++myIterator)
{
   for(vector<string>::const_iterator myOtherIterator = *myIterator.begin();     
      myOtherIterator != *myIterator.end(); ++myOtherIterator)
   {
      cout << *myOtherIterator << " ";
   }
   cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Can't upvote because my reputation isn't high enough but thanks so much for not only solving but also explaining why!

Answer (score 1):

My guess, and it's only a guess because you're not showing all the necessary code to know, is that you're using the wrong iterator type.  It appears based on the compiler vomit that you need to be using const_iterator because your objects are constant.

You can't assign to the key part of a associative container (like multiset).  This means your vector is const.  You need const iterator to iterate it.

The multiset appears to be non-const.  You do not need a const iterator to navigate it.  The const nature of the value type it contains will protect against assigning to the key.

Comment: This is all of the code there is in the program except for the #include 's etc. But thanks for trying.

Comment: Oh, I thought it was a snippet.  The problem is then that you can't do execution statements like this outside of a function.  You can perform assignments that can call a function or execute a single statement, but you can't have large sections of statements outside of a function.

Answer (score 1):

having a plain `multiset<XXX>::iterator myIterator` is wrong, because if you do a 
`*myIterator = ...;` then you'll have wrecked the multiset.

use `const_iterator` instead

```
for (multiset< vector <string > >::const_iterator myIterator = setOfRules.begin(); myIterator!=setOfRules.end(); ++myIterator) {
```

Comment: I think you'll find that you're applying this in the wrong place.  It's the other loop's iterator that needs to be const.  Doing so here won't hurt anything, but won't solve the problem either.